# Layout for drag/drop/connect things

Tags: gratis, library, javascript, drag-drop

I'm looking for a JavaScript library/framework that allows to drag & drop things, and then to (dis)connect and remove them.

A good example about what I need is [Juju Charms](https://jujucharms.com/inspector/27565479$/):

> [image]

So, I'm able to drag items from sidebar to the main screen and use them (connect, move, delete, select etc).

I'd prefer using canvas or svg.

Any recommendations?